# How and why handle jwt token expiration with refresh_token, is there another alternative?

Tags: java, authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, refresh-token

I have two wars: `app.war`(struts web app) and `rest.war`(classic rest api).

`app.war` access `rest.war` by jwt token which is generated once user login `app.war` successful.

When user use `a.war`, some data need to be got from `rest.war` by sending ajax calls from jsp of `a.war` with jwt token.

The expired time of jwt token is 15 mins, while session timeout of `app.war` is 1 hour.

However, if jwt token is expired, there is pop up ask for user login again even and user still can access `app.war`.

There is one alternative: use `access_token` and `refresh_token`, if `access_token` expired, then use `refresh_token` to get new `access_token` and `refresh_token`.

For this approach, I have some questions:

**First**, Why use two tokens? because i think they are the same, just `refresh_token` live longer than  `access_token` and use `refresh_token` to get new `access_token`, so why not just `access_token` and set its expired time longer?

**Second**, is it same algorithms to generate `access_token` and `refresh_token`, just their expired is different?

**Third**, if client perform several api invocations (sync & async) using the token, how handle if one of that invocations return the 401 (token expired) ?

Comment: i don't know why it is closed. i think it focused on one problem only : jwt token expired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said, refresh_token is the recommended alternative to deal with jwt expiration.

## why use two tokens?

Because the use of two tokens (access_token and refresh_token) is a verified strategy used by world class companies (google, azure, amazon, etc) which trust in **The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework**

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

Which is a product of the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) which in turn is : The Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) is an open standards organization, which develops and promotes voluntary Internet standards, in particular the standards that comprise the Internet protocol suite.

You can use the oauth2 framework rigidly complying its [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749), create and hybrid focus on your custom requirements or develop a new framework with new concepts

## so why not just access_token and set its expired time longer?

Oauth2 spec does not recommend a non-expirable token. Token word itself mean a expirable thing. If it doesn't expire, we could use a password.

For example let's imagine a mobile app which needs a token to download some user information. If token does not expire, a thief could steal the mobile app, enter and access to the user info. But as token means expiration, the thief could have a time limited access. Also token could be [revoked](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7009) by the user at the steal time, so the thief could not has access.

Commonly when token expire, a login is forced. But there some requirements in which user doesn't want to login and login again every 3600 ms. So **refresh_token** helps to don't disturb to our user and **get a new access_token without human login**. Now, what happen if **refresh_token** didn't expire? Can we create access-tokens from months or years? That is why **refresh_token must expire too**

## is it same algorithms to generate access_token and refresh_token, just their expired is different?

I implemented a kind of security server and I used the same algorithm with different expiration. But I added a extra claim to to differentiate them:

- [How to differentiate refresh_token from access_token at validation stage in security server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59812826/how-to-differentiate-refresh-token-from-access-token-at-validation-stage-in-secu)

## Several invocations needs the access_token

In this case, if token is renewed at every user login, you will have an access_token ready to use with 3600ms of life.

After that your user is kind of robot ( or is a feature/requirement of your web ) and start to use multiple forms which perform several invocations to your rest api attaching the access_token.

If we are in the 3601ms, in the next api invocation from web, the api must return a 403 error and show a classic popup: **Session expired, click here to login again...**

If your requirement is avoid this popup, you could choice one of these approaches:

- Renew token  using the refresh token on 403 error. In this case you could use [axios-retry](https://github.com/softonic/axios-retry) to deal with retry on error.
- After login, start an async task to renew the token at intervals less than token expiration. 3400ms in our example. So api invocations from your web never fail

## Advice

Perform access_token and refresh_token exchange in your backend layer, not in frontend (ajax) layer.

So the attackers  will never know your endpoint to get tokens or refresh them.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. you said `Perform access_token and refresh_token exchange in your backend layer, not in frontend (ajax) layer.`, what do you mean? do you mean `access_token` and `refresh_token` should not store in the user client such that frontend(ajax) doesn't need to send them?

Comment: i don't know why it is closed, if it is closed, i don't know whether the bounty can assign to you. sorry about that.

Comment: I tried to improve your question. I think is a valid and could help others to understand how `refresh_token` works, but it had several questions inside :s